# VSTO Cached dataset becoming NULL

Tags: vsto

We have a VSTO Excel add-in that is capable of loading data by making web service calls. Once we get the data through web service response, we save it to a dataset and load it on the Excel sheet with the help of a list object. Now the dataset is always cached so that when the user opens the workbook next time, we need not make a web service call again to load data. It must load with the cached dataset.

The problem is, for some workbooks (Not all), the dataset is saving and loading properly after first save of the workbook. But, the same dataset is becoming null after second save onwards. The dataset has 4200+ records with 150+ columns. I would like to mention that after second save onwards, all other cached variables are having values. Only the cached dataset is null. Following points to better understand the problem.

- Open the Excel template, load data via web service calls. (dataset is loaded now)
- Save and close the workbook.
- Reopen the same workbook. Dataset is still intact. Loads workbook properly.
- Save and close the workbook.
- Reopen the same workbook. Dataset is null. So data cannot be loaded to Excel. Existing excel rows are getting deleted as  list object behaves as if it was opened for the first time.

Does anyone have any idea what could be wrong? We are using .NET framework 3.5/4.0 and Excel 2007. Excel 2010 does not create any problem.

Comment: Where is the DataSet being cached? Can you show some code?

Comment: The dataset is cached in one of the Worksheets of the workbook. For Example,                                                   namespace MyProject
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Represents the Sheet1 worksheet host item
    /// </summary>
    public partial class Sheet1
    {
        #region Cached Properties

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the dataset property.        /// </summary> 
        /// <remarks>This property is stored in the data cache</remarks>
        [Cached]
        public DataSet MyDataSet { get; set; }...